# Python, mechanize, proper syntax for setting multiple headers?

Tags: python, http-headers, mechanize, webautomation

I can't seem to find how to do this anywere, I am trying to set multiple headers with python's mechanize module, such as:

```
br.addheaders = [('user-agent', '   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3')]
br.addheaders = [('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]
```

But it seems that it only takes the last br.addheaders.. so it only shows the 'accept' header, not the 'user-agent' header, which leads me to believe that each call to 'br.addheaders' overwrites any previous calls to this.. I can't figure the syntax to include 2 or more headers so I would greatly appreciate any help..

I am using this website to test headers output:

http://www.ericgiguere.com/tools/http-header-viewer.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers, the syntax would be

```
br.addheaders = [('user-agent', '   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3'),
('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]
```

That is, make a list of header tuples.

Comment: thanks.. I tried that before but it didn't work, maybe i made some other syntax error without realizing it.. will try it again.. I need to bookmark that api page since its really confusing how to get to it (at least to me) from the main mechanize page that comes up in google

Comment: Which means, of course, that you can add further headers as you can add elements to any other list: `br.addheaders.append(("Accept-Language", "en-us,en"))`

Comment: I added header using this method, but after br.open(url) when I check br.request.headers it returns OrderedDict([]). Any idea, why this is empty?