# httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, urllib2, mechanize-python

I am using python 2.7 on windows and
I know already there are posts regarding this question, but all I want to know how to resolve this problem on windows since in few post like these-

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564509/python-mechanize-proper-syntax-for-setting-multiple-headers)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096885/python-mechanize-request-disallowed-by-robots-txt-even-after-set-handle-robot)

And the links in few answers there is this code-

```
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

**What are these parameters? May I please know how to do this on windows** and if any nice documentation/ guide on libraries of python eg- mechanize from this error perspection will be of great help.

Also please someone guide me is this error caused by mechanize or urllib2.

And if it is caused by mechanize then why urllib2 is referred in few posts on stackoverflow.

I sincerely apologize for not asking this properly and/or may be re-asking this question since I am new to these libraries. Super thanks for any kind of help !